# How to install a desktop GUI on WSL2?

Tags: 22.04, xfce, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-desktop, xrdp

A newbie here. I spent a couple weeks trying to use a desktop GUI on WSL using `xfce4` and `xrdp`. I already tried a couple ways, following some tutorials to make it work, had no success though. So I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here are the tutorials I tried:

1. https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-22-04/
2. https://ubunlog.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-with-graphical-interface-in-windows-thanks-to-wsl2-or-better-even-kali-linux/
3. https://gist.github.com/Ta180m/e1471413f62e3ed94e72001d42e77e22 I also tried this one without using `ubuntu-desktop` or `ubuntu-desktop-minimal` but `xfce4` and `gnome`.

For tutorials 1 and 2, the remote desktop app on Windows can't connect, and when it does, this happens: the login screen appears, after login the connection is aborted closing the screen instance, or shows me an alert with "return" *Display=0*, or the screen turns black.

There are other tutorials for that last issue. I tried them and nothing happened.

*Display=0* error image example:

[image: Display=0 error image example]

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

WSL2 supports native Linux desktop GUI applications without the need to install specific desktop environment like with the original version of WSL.

Simply install the application you're after with apt or snap, and run it - a new window will pop up with the linux GUI application running natively in Windows - Full steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps).